# Java - Making a Custom Field

Tags: java, oop

I have a class CustomTextField and CustomPasswordField . The first extends the JTextField and the second the JPasswordField class. Both have the same code inside but only the super class differs. How can i make a single class instead of two ? Something like this:

```
class CustomTextField extends JTextField{
      public CustomTextField(int col){
             super(col);
      }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            // Drawing custom shape with transparent color
            super.paintComponent(g);
      }
}

class CustomPasswordField extends JPasswordField{
      public CustomPasswordField(int col){
             super(col);
      }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            // Drawing custom shape with transparent color
            super.paintComponent(g);
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

**Update:**

I could extend like this:

```
class InputField extends JPasswordField{
      // code and paintComponent override
}
```

... and to cast to JTextField every time i need a text field like this:

```
JTextField field = new InputField();
```

but it seems that it still behaves like  JPasswordField (it uses * instead of characters)

Comment: You can extend a generic class, but you can't extend a generic type. If you explain what you're trying to accomplish with that, maybe we can help you with the correct solution.

Comment: ok. Is there a way to implement that code ?

Comment: "How can I implement this" - implement what?

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do? Don't tell how you're trying to solve the problem, tell us the problem.

Comment: JPasswordField extends JTextField so you could just extend JPasswordField and you'd be able to use whatever methods JTextField has too?

Comment: The code i wrote above. Is there a way to achive what i wanted to describe in that code ?

Comment: I have a class CustomTextField and CustomPasswordField . The first extends the JTextField and the second the JPasswordField class. Both have the same code inside but only the super class differs. How can i make a single class instead of two?

Comment: Edit your question to include the text of your comment.  That's the real question you're asking.

Comment: You want to say that i should extend to JPasswordField and when i need it to be as a JTextFIeld to make a cast ?

Comment: Maybe tell us what your goal is, why you want to extends those 2 classes which are already in the same hierarchy.

Comment: I think you need to do some research into polymorphism, basically, an apple is also a type of fruit, but that doesn't stop it from been an apple

Answer (score 0):

T is the generic type not a real class. It is just a placeholder for a type that will be set by the callee when he calls you. If he calls you with `<String>`, `T` will be `String`.

This is not what you asked for but maybe what you are looking for:

You can use inheritance in the typing, so you can define that T has to be related to some other Class
`<T extends Something>` and `<T super Something>`

With `<T extends Something>` you can be sure that any type passed to you is at least a Something or a class extending from Something.